# JPA/JPQL returns incomplete results with WHERE x.y IS NULL OR x.y.z = 1

Tags: java, sql, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I have the following SQL returning 13 results

```sql
SELECT *
FROM AAA a
JOIN BBB b ON b.id = a.b_id
LEFT JOIN CCC c ON c.id = b.c_id
LEFT JOIN DDD d ON d.id = c.d_id
WHERE b.c_id IS NULL
OR d.status = 1
```

And following JPQL returning 3 results

```
SELECT a
FROM AAA a
WHERE a.b.c IS NULL
```

And following JPQL returning 10 results

```
SELECT a
FROM AAA a
WHERE a.b.c.d.status = 1
```

But the following JPQL returns 10 results, missing the 3 null ones.

```
SELECT a
FROM AAA a
WHERE a.b.c IS NULL
OR a.b.c.d.status = 1
```

What am I missing? Where do I begin debugging this?

Comment: a.b.c.d generates (implicit) **inner** joins

Comment: and also missing actually looking at the generated SQL for those JPQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where do I begin debugging this?

If you're uncertain about your ORM, tune the log level so you could see the generated SQL queries or directly check database logs.

> What am I missing?

Condition `WHERE a.b.c.d.status = 1` forces jpa provider to create inner joins for all tables in the path (BBB, CCC, DDD). This neutralizes OR condition `a.b.c IS NULL`.